# How do I use intersection types in an angular template

Tags: angular, typescript, angular15

I encountered a problem when using intersection types in an angular template. In my component typescript file I have following input:

```js
export class ExampleClassComponent {
  ...
  @Input() items: Array<InfoItem> | Array<InfoItemWithAction> = [];
  ...
}
```

InfoItem is an interface and InfoItemWithAction is an intersection type, defined as follow:

```js
export interface InfoItem {
  value: string;
  name?: string;
}

export type InfoItemWithAction = InfoItem & { action: ActionType; id: number };
```

When using looping over the items array inside my template file, each item is narrowed down to only "value" and "name", since those properties are the only one matching in both parts.

```js
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let item of items">
    <div>
      {{ item.name }} {{ item.value }}
    </div>

    <button *ngIf="item.action" (click)="onActionClicked(item)"> --> throws unknown property "action"
      <span [class.color]="item.action === 'delete' ? 'warn' : null"> --> throws unknown property "action"
        {{ item.action }} --> throws unknown property "action"
      </span>
    </button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

This makes perfectly sense, but I couldn't find a way to solve this problem.

I've tried a type guard but this lead to a function check every time I wanted to use item.action which seems pretty ugly.

Just using item['action'] as an index type isn't an option either.

I could create a new component for each type, but I don't want to do this.

Does anybody has an idea?

Comment: Have you tried using `*ngIf="'action' in item"` yet?

Answer (score 0):

Since `item` may or may not have an `action` property, typescript wants you to verify that it's there before trying to access it. The `in` operator is an easy way to do this:

```
<button *ngIf="'action' in item" (click)="onActionClicked(item)">
```

```
<span [class.color]="'action' in item && item.action === 'delete' ? 'warn' : null">
```